# ¿Cómo puedo agregar / quitar una clase a un elemento cuando es una determinada URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Cómo puedo agregar / quitar una clase a un elemento cuando la URL?

Quiero hacerlo con if

un ejemplo

```
if url

{   addclass('active'); //true

} else {

removeclass('active'); //false

}
```

```js
var url = window.location.href; 

$('.info-project').find('a').each(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active', $(this).attr('href') == url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info-project">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: No entiendo, tú mismo te has dado la respuesta al inicio de la redacción. Solo haz un condicional de la URL y aplica/elimina la clase según aplique el caso o no.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía un condicional de la Url y la clase active, solo home con active y blog no active. click blog con active y home no active.

Comment: Cuando `/` => link Home debe activarse y cuando `/blog` => link Blog debe activarse. ¿Es eso?

Comment: @GustavoGarcía Si asi es.

Comment: el problema que tienes es que estas agregando un estilo que ni siquiera lo tienes definido

Comment: @JackNavaRow Se supone que ya tiene la clase CSS, caso contrario no tendría sentido preguntar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que yo siempre hago es quitar todos los enlaces que son activos y activar solo el que está activo:

```
$('.info-project a').removeClass('active');
$('.info-project [href=#]').addClass('active');
```

> Con el selector por atributo `[href=#]`, puedo filtrar aquellos enlaces que apuntan a determinada URL.

### Ejemplo:

Seleccionaré el home, esperaré 5 segundos y seleccionaré blog.

```js
var url = window.location.href;

// deselecciono todos los enlaces y selecciono home
$('.info-project a').removeClass('active');
$('.info-project a[href="#"]').addClass('active');

// Y después de 5 segundos.. 
setTimeout(function() {
  // deselecciono todos los enlaces y selecciono blog 
  $('.info-project a').removeClass('active');
  $('.info-project a[href="/blog"]').addClass('active');
}, 5000);
```

```css
.info-project a.active {
  font-weight: 800;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info-project">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que haces. ¿estás basando tu respuesta en una SPA? Porque en una aplicación tradicional no tiene sentido que todos los links estén `activos` por defecto.

Comment: Estoy suponiendo que está trabajando con `ajax`, y cuando le da clic a otro enlace, necesita marcar los demás como inactivos, si no en todo caso basta con `$('.info-project a[href="#"]').addClass('active');` remplazando `#` con la url.

Comment: Me parece que interpreté mal la pregunta, ya que en ningún momento el OP habla de [tag:ajax]. Es mejor no responder hasta tener certeza de lo que usa/desea.

Comment: Tienes razón, no lo dice, pero la pregunta dice como agregar y quitar, así que ahí está la respuesta. Saludos.